# how to make slave system to access Git repository in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I am new to Jenkins.I have a master slave configuration.I have a Job that runs on the slave and it needs to pull data from Git repository and process them.I have configured the job in master.But when I try to build the Job i get

`Error:Error Cloning remote repo origin`

Is there something that needs to be done to make the slave have access to the repository.Please Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301729/jenkins-error-cloning-remote-repo-origin-slave-node Here is a similar problem but without any answers

Comment: Hey, I just added a response to the question from @RCBian 's link.  It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your git repo asks for authentication, you have to configure it on Jenkins.
The slaves will automatically get that configuration and try to clone using it.

Comment: My git repo doesnt ask for authentication.When I try to use git on the master I am able to access it.the problem is with slave confugartion