# Should I run Jenkins by command line instead of as a service?

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins

I have been running Jenkins as a service on EC2 for a while. The problem is that since it's being run as a service, the chrome browser size is smaller than what we need. We are now running it using command line (not as a service) so it has a bigger browser size now. The only issue that I've observed so far was that the performance decreased. It took 1:30h for a 50mins jobs.

Should I keep running it using command line? Any other concerns that I need to worry about? (except the performance issue) Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `Jenkins as a service`?

Comment: Do you mean by using the API calls?

Comment: @chenrui Hi, so when server starts it will run jenkins.exe as a service automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps, might help you out

Stop the service (Jenkins.exe)

> Right Click >> Properties >> Log On TAB >> Local System Account >> Check Allow service to interact with Desktop
>    then it will take the resolution of the monitor you currently use.

Make sure you put `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()`; in your script.

Let me know if this does not works out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I run as you instructed, all of the jobs now cannot download any codes form github repo: ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'. I've been searching around and setup some SSH key but it didn't solve that issue. Do you have any ideas? thanks

Comment: Can you check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301729/jenkins-error-cloning-remote-repo-origin-slave-node

Comment: I have tried all the solutions but none of them works. I need to switch back to run as .\Administrator