# Jenkins ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I'm trying the first steps using Jenkins, but did not succeed managing the first pipeline test. I'm using the latest Jenkins helm chart for Kubernetes.

I'm trying to run this simple pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'php'
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'php --v'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The source code is hosted on GitHub, the repository seems to be connected correctly. My pipeline always fails:

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://github.com/yoghurt1001/WebsiteInfo.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/WebsiteInfo_master # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/yoghurt1001/WebsiteInfo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHub Access Token
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/yoghurt1001/WebsiteInfo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/yoghurt1001/WebsiteInfo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 137:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:629)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:181)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.244.2.240/10.244.2.240:51982
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:389)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:50)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

Before this jenkins did a step that succeeded using git:
[image: Jenkins build output]
Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong? I've also tried the same pipeline on some Bitbucket Server repositories with the same result.

Felix

Comment: Have u checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301729/jenkins-error-cloning-remote-repo-origin-slave-node ?
Looks similar to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is related to [issue JENKINS-50132](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50132)

> Issue is resolved after increasing the memory to 1024 Mi and CPU to 500m, earlier it was using the default settings from Kubernetes cluster which was 256Mi and 200m.